# HTML elements in an email have weird string prepended to their ID?

Tags: html, email, selenium-webdriver, html-email

I have a service that is automatically sending email reports. I'm currently trying to stand up some automated testing to ensure that the data in the emails are correct.

I'm assigning some unique IDs to various HTML elements in my email templates, then using selenium in my tests to grab those elements, and grab the text.

This is working, but for whatever reason, the ID that I assign has some odd string pre-pended at the beginning. For example I have an element in my template that looks like this:

```html
<td id="siteInfo" class="site-subtitle">
```

and then once the email is sent, the element that I find looks like this:

```html
<td id="m_-6467880284962569820siteInfo" style="font-family:'Roboto',Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:600">
```

What is this `m_-6467880284962569820`? It prepends the ID of every element that I assigned an ID in the template. It is the same for each ID, although it changes each time I send the email.

I can pretty easily just ignore this part of the ID, but I'm curious as to what it is coming from? This is a gmail account that I am testing with.

Comment: This kind of looks like, the ID is generated dynamically. You will see this on many applications. Try to inspect the search field of twitch, then open another tab and inspect the same thing. The ID will be different.

Comment: Just as Nathan answered below all classes and ID's will be prepended dynamically. That is both in your code at each element level and in the style. if you emails work as expected then you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does this to differentiate styles from one email to another, and to the broader page. Otherwise, styles might interact/override, because they are not in iframes, but the code is brought into the one page.

You'll also notice the `<body>` tag is changed to a `<div>` and some other changes.